# How do you de-embed a shorted 2-port fixture?

Tags: testing, calibration, s-parameters, vna, power-integrity

I've been working through reproducing Steve Sandler's 2-port shunt-through measurements ([2019 SIJ article](https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/articles/1202-the-2-port-shunt-thru-measurement-and-the-inherent-ground-loop), [Picotest slide-deck](https://www.picotest.com/images/download/two-Port-Shunt-Thru-Impedance.pdf)). My target is to measure capacitors with ESR down to 1 mΩ with an accuracy of at least 10%. I've had good success with a common-mode transformer with > 30 dB CM insertion loss when measuring a 1.5 mΩ resistor.

I'm now trying to figure out how to de-embed fixture parasitics (inductance and remaining ground-loop error). [The 2024 issue of SIJ, page 42](https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/ext/resources/Digital-SIJ-Issues/2024/SIJ-EBOOK-2024-v1.pdf) shows *why* de-embedding is important, and shows how to configure the fixture with a short (with an ideal short in EM simulation, or with a low-resistance piece of copper of similar size to the DUT on the physical fixture), but I'm unclear on how to actually *implement* the de-embedding algorithm for a 2x THRU shorted fixture.

[image: From SIJ 2024]

---

**Can anyone please point me to resources on how to de-embed the shorted fixture from the measurement?** I think I *could* subtract ESR and ESL from the DUT measurement, but I'd like to generate s2p files that I can use in an EM solver.